# Running a GITLAB CI Pipeline job (.gitlab-ci.yml) before merging the changes

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to create the gitlab pipeline job in which i need to execute the component testing before merging my changes in to the main branch

i tried multiple blogs but i am not getting the information clearly.

Can someone please asssit me on this ?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what component testing means.